# Cant create a Sudoku level with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sudoku

I'm making a Sudoku that runs in terminal with python, and I can't assign numbers to fill up the board with numbers. Here is my code with all functions and main program. I think the error is in the checker for the number.

```py
def createBoard ():
    rows = 9
    columns = 9
    matrix = []
    for r in range(rows):
        matrix.append([])  # agregar lista
        for c in range(columns):
            matrix[r].append("")

    return matrix


def printBoard (board):
    for i in range (len(board)):
        print (board[i])

def defineSubMatrix (row, column):

    subMatrix = -1

    if row >= 0 and row <= 2:
        if column >= 0 and column <= 2:
            subMatrix = 0
        if column >= 3 and column <= 5:
            subMatrix = 1
        if column >= 6 and column <= 8:
            subMatrix = 2

    if row >= 3 and row <= 5:
        if column >= 0 and column <= 2:
            subMatrix = 3
        if column >= 3 and column <= 5:
            subMatrix = 4
        if column >= 6 and column <= 8:
            subMatrix = 5

    if row >= 3 and row <= 5:
        if column >= 0 and column <= 2:
            subMatrix = 6
        if column >= 3 and column <= 5:
            subMatrix = 7
        if column >= 6 and column <= 8:
            subMatrix = 8

    return  subMatrix

def createLevel (board):
    for i in range (0, 8):
        for j in range (0, 8):
            num = random.randint (1, 9)
            
            check = checker(board, num, i, j)

            while check == False:
                if check == False:

                    num = random.randint (1, 9)
                    check = checker(board, num, i, j)

                board[i][j] = num

            board[i][j] = num

    return board


def checker (board, num, posX, posY):
    ### ok = True cuando check == 0
    ok = False
    checkT = 0
    checkR = 0
    checkC = 0
    checkSM = 0

    ###Check row right
    i = posX
    while i + 1 <= 8:
        if board[i][posY] == num:
            checkR += 1
        i = i + 1

    ###Check row left
    i = posX
    while i - 1 >= 0:
        if board[i][posY] == num:
            checkR += 1
        i = i - 1

    ###Check column down
    j = posY
    while j + 1 <= 8:
        if board[posX][j] == num:
            checkC += 1
        j = j + 1

    ###Check column up
    j = posY
    while j - 1 >= 0:
        if board[posX][j] == num:
            checkC += 1
        j = j - 1


    ###Check Submatrix
    subMatrix = defineSubMatrix(posX, posY)
    if subMatrix == 0:
        for i in range (0, 2):
            for j in range (0, 2):
                if board[i][j] == num:
                    checkSM += 1

    if subMatrix == 1:
        for i in range (3, 5):
            for j in range (0, 2):
                if board[i][j] == num:
                    checkSM += 1

    if subMatrix == 2:
        for i in range (6, 8):
            for j in range (0, 2):
                if board[i][j] == num:
                    checkSM += 1

    if subMatrix == 3:
        for i in range (0, 2):
            for j in range (3, 5):
                if board[i][j] == num:
                    checkSM += 1

    if subMatrix == 4:
        for i in range (3, 5):
            for j in range (3, 5):
                if board[i][j] == num:
                    checkSM += 1

    if subMatrix == 5:
        for i in range (6, 8):
            for j in range (3, 5):
                if board[i][j] == num:
                    checkSM += 1

    if subMatrix == 6:
        for i in range (0, 2):
            for j in range (6, 8):
                if board[i][j] == num:
                    checkSM += 1

    if subMatrix == 7:
        for i in range (3, 5):
            for j in range (6, 8):
                if board[i][j] == num:
                    checkSM += 1

    if subMatrix == 8:
        for i in range (6, 8):
            for j in range (6, 8):
                if board[i][j] == num:
                    checkSM += 1

    checkT = checkR + checkSM + checkC

    if checkT == 0:
        ok = True

    return ok

def main ():
    board = createBoard()

    subma = defineSubMatrix(0, 6)
    print (subma)

    printBoard(board)
    print ("Board Created")

    level = createLevel(board)
    print ("Level created")

    printBoard(level)

    
###PROGRAMA
main()
```

Comment: What exactly happens, what should happen?

Comment: The PRIMARY thing you have missed about Python is that `range(0,2)` produces 0 and 1.  The end value is always exclusive.  If you want (0,1,2), then you either need `range(0,3)`, or just write `(0,1,2)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't create a Sudoku this way, by just making random selections.  You quickly get into a situation like this:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
4 5 6 1 2 3 . . .
```

and now there are no possibilities for the next cells.

Many Sudoku algorithms create the grids the same way humans solve them, using complicated heuristics.  It is possible to use brute force.  Consider that every Sudoku puzzle can be derived from every other Sudoku puzzle, by using a combination of (a) swapping rows, (b) swapping columns, (c) swapping sets of 3 rows, (d) swapping sets of 3 columns, (e) rotating 90 degrees, and (f) mirroring across one of the axes.  Given that, you can start with a well ordered matrix like this:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
4 5 6 7 8 9 1 2 3
7 8 9 1 2 3 4 5 6
2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 1
5 6 7 8 9 2 3 4 5
8 9 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
3 4 5 6 7 8 9 1 2
6 7 8 9 1 2 3 4 5
9 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

and then doing random swaps, rotates, and mirrors, just like shuffling a deck of cards.  See this article:

https://www.algosome.com/articles/create-a-solved-sudoku.html